# Pandas DataFrame - iterating

Tags: python, pandas, iteration, python-3.7

First of all - i know that iterating over Pandas DataFrame is not a good idea, so any suggestions regarding the other possible solutions are welcome.

I am trying to write a little piece of code to compare two dataframes - one of which is a template to compare with.

The dataframes look like this (shortened version, of course):

Template:

```
            Template1 | Template2 | Template3 
----------------------+-----------+------------
Variable 1 |  value   |   value   |   value     
Variable 2 |  value   |   value   |   value     
Variable 3 |  value   |   value   |   value     
Variable 4 |  value   |   value   |   value
```

And the file to compare (datafile):

```
            Record 1 | Record 2 | Record 3 | Record 4
---------------------+----------+----------+----------
Variable 3 |  value  |  value   |  value   |  value  
Variable 1 |  value  |  value   |  value   |  value  
Variable 4 |  value  |  value   |  value   |  value
```

Now, what the script should do:

- take one, specific column from template file
- compare every record in data file with the selected column

I managed to write a little piece of code and it even works for one record:

```
template = templatefile['Template2']
record_to_check = datafile[0]

errors_found = []
for a in template.index:
    if a in record_to_check.index:
        variable = {}
        if template[a] == record_to_check[a]:
            # equal
            pass
        else:
            # unequal
            variable['name'] = a
            variable['value'] = template[a]
            errors_found.append(variable)
    else:
        # not found
        variable = {}
        variable['name'] = a
        variable['value'] = template[a]
        errors_found.append(variable)
```

It returns dictionary of errors_found, containing pair of {variable:value}.
Problem starts when i am trying to put it in another loop (to iterate over the records in datafile:

```
template = templatefile['Template2']

for record_to_check in datafile.iteritems():
    errors_found = []
    for a in template.index:
        if a in record_to_check.index:
            variable = {}
            if template[a] == record_to_check[a]:
                # equal
                pass
            else:
                # unequal
                variable['name'] = a
                variable['value'] = template[a]
                errors_found.append(variable)
        else:
            # not found
            variable = {}
            variable['name'] = a
            variable['value'] = template[a]
            errors_found.append(variable)
```

result:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "attributes.py", line 24, in <module>
    if a in record_to_check.index:
TypeError: argument of type 'builtin_function_or_method' is not iterable
```

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: expected output should be dictionary like this:

```
[{'name': 'variable2', 'value': value_from_template}, {'name': 'variable3', 'value': value_from_template}]
```

And i know that if i run it in the loop it would overwrite the dictionary for each iteration. I just wanted to be sure that it works with multiple records, so i can make function out of it.

Comment: Your condition for checking if a in atm.index is wrong. In case indices are int then you can use == to check for possible match.

Comment: Also can you add your desired output

Comment: Edited, fixed and added. I should add that the order of the rows may differ between template and datafile and in the datafile some variables may be missing - hence the checking `if a in record_to_check.index`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you point out yourself, looping over a pandas dataframe is not a good approach. Instead you should use a join, here are some ideas:

Assuming you have the reference table

```
template
        template1   template2
index                        
var 1           1           5
var 2           2           4
var 3           3           3
var 4           4           2
```

and your data table

```
datafile
        record1   record2
index                    
var 3         1         3
var 1         2         3
var 4         4         2
```

- A left join on the indices will automatically match the variables, the ordering does not play a role: `joined = template.join(datafile, how='left')`.
- You can then easily create new columns that tell you whether the values in the template and data table match: `joined['temp1=rec1'] = joined["template1"] == joined["record1"]`.
- This column you can use to show only those rows where the values do not match: `errors_found = joined[~joined['temp1=rec1']]`

```
errors_found
        template1   template2   record1   record2  temp1=rec1
index                                                        
var 1           1           5       2.0       3.0       False
var 2           2           4       NaN       NaN       False
var 3           3           3       1.0       3.0       False
```

- You can now get a dictionary with the template values: `errors_found = joined[~joined['temp1=rec1']]['template 1'].to_dict()`

```
{'var 1': 1, 'var 2': 2, 'var 3': 3}
```

If you want this for more than just one column pair, you can put this code in a function and loop / map over the columns.

Hope this helps.